# Does coredns compiled binary not contain all the plugins compiled along with?

Tags: go, coredns

When I try to use proxy, I get error saying "proxy directive not found".

```
. {
    proxy . 8.8.8.8:53 {
        protocol https_google
    }
    prometheus
    errors
    log
}
```

I also tried to compile coredns using Go but I got lot of errors from the plugins and Go binary wasn't generated in the bin folder instead a new binary acmeprobe was there.

Comment: Do `coredns -plugins` to list what plugins your current install has. Also what kind of errors did you get, and how did you try to build it?

Comment: Ah it does have a huge list. So was proxy plugin renamed to forward ?

Comment: Looks like it! Agreed, Vancouver is a lovely place :).